# How to use Dojo Dijit select without tables?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm working on some project that uses Dojo `dijit.form.Select`, that produce some really strange HTML. It's replace standard browser select with `table`, `tr`, `td` and other crap that made it slow (a lot of unnecessary elements), inaccessible (select by letter doesn't work) and very hard to style.

Is there any why to tell Dojo to switch into standards mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to override the template (you can check in dijit/form/template/select.html)
You'll need to override it, but keep the attachpoint and vars I guess.
I'd recommend checking that and if the original Select.js writes hard coded html which would mean you would also have to override these functions.

In any case, this does not seem like a simple switch off property.
In the end you might want to simply call a normal select and handle it with a custom made controller widget...

Comment: Dojo is zipped in the .jar... How to customize select template without modify Dojo sources? (I'm new to Dojo)

Comment: I guess that means that dojo has been "built". Basically, you could "extend" the select, or simply, when you create a new instance of the select, programmatically change the template property, then build again as a .jar maybe?

Comment: Sorry then, don't know much more on this architecture of yours, you'll have to find out how to change that as I said in your repo :/